# Flexbox growing out of parent at some screen size

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design, media-queries

I need to create 3 flexbox items in a row that have to be responsive. In almost all size of screen the render is like I want, but at some size the flexbox container that is in light-coral grow up over the container itself in light-blue. I try to use different options like put a max-width to container but still don't work.
Can you help me understand how can I solve this.
Thanks
[image: Flexbox out of container]

```css
@media (max-width:480px) {
  .container-content {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

.container {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 10px;
}

.container-content {
  justify-content: space-around;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
  align-items: center;
}

.container * {
  background-color: lightcoral;
}

.child,
picture {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.child .title {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #5E6420;
  font-family: Ano Bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-content">
    <div class="child">
      <img src="photo.svg" alt="">
      <div class="title">SNAP</div>
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad, ea error! Ratione, magnam sequi facere nam, iusto ab corrupti recusandae autem tempore sit vero sapiente qui quaerat eum sed commodi?</div>
    </div>
    <picture>
      <source media="(max-width:480px)" srcset="arrow-mb.svg">
      <source media="(min-width:481px)" srcset="arrow.svg">
      <img src="arrow.svg" alt="Arrow">
    </picture>

    <div class="child">
      <img src="photo.svg" alt="">
      <div class="title">SNAP</div>
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad, ea error! Ratione, magnam sequi facere nam, iusto ab corrupti recusandae autem tempore sit vero sapiente qui quaerat eum sed commodi?</div>
    </div>
    <picture>
      <source media="(max-width:480px)" srcset="arrow-mb.svg">
      <source media="(min-width:481px)" srcset="arrow.svg">
      <img src="arrow.svg" alt="Arrow">
    </picture>
    <div class="child">
      <img src="photo.svg" alt="">
      <div class="title">SNAP</div>
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad, ea error! Ratione, magnam sequi facere nam, iusto ab corrupti recusandae autem tempore sit vero sapiente qui quaerat eum sed commodi?</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use grid instead, follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rg7Fvvl3taU)

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen Can you help me achieve this with flexbox not grid

Comment: grid was made to fix this issue that you're having with flex-box

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen Did you mean that there is no option to do this with FlexBox ?

Comment: yes rony, but use grid, its the best way to do this

Comment: look at [this example using grid](https://jsfiddle.net/koc358d0/)

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen Thanks. But now there is no 3 items in a row but only two. Moreover in my example in phone size the item is one below the other and now it's not the case. Did you know why ?

Comment: you need to open it on a large screen

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen if I want that in any desktop screen size it will be 3 item in all same row. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

You could add `overflow: auto;` to your flexbox container.

Comment: I don't want overflow. I want that the inner container will be 90% width of parent container no matter the screen size and with no overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Problem (51% sure about):
3 rows is too small for text, 90% only and padding:10px.
So you would need a e.g. `word-break: break-all;`

Looks like the div width is smaller as the content in 1 line /a long word, including the padding: 10px.
After i added a `word-break: break-all;` the problem loooks like it is solved.
So in small sizes reduce the padding (?).

Comment: I add to class .container a padding 0 when max-width is under 480px but not solve problem

Answer (score 0):

Just add a rule in your media query which makes the arrow images shorter (= less wide) on smaller screens. Their practically fixed size is the main reason that everything else has too little space.

Comment: This is svg image how can I reduce the size of them on small screen ?

Comment: Here' an article about scaling SVGs: https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/ 
But actually, it's probably faster to find PNG images of arrows (i.e. google it) whose size you can easily handle with CSS.